# create .xls file using php

Tags: php, excel, export, fwrite

This is what I have:

```
   $sep = "\t";        //tabbed character
    $fp = fopen('registrars.xls', "w");

$schema_insert_rows = "";
//printing column names 

        $schema_insert_rows.="#" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows.="Registrar" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows.="Country" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows.="Website" . $sep;
        //$schema_insert_rows.="Postal Address" . $sep;
        //$schema_insert_rows.="Contact Number" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows.="Email Address" . $sep;

        $schema_insert_rows.="\n";
        fwrite($fp, $schema_insert_rows);

// printing data:
    $row = 0; $i = 0; $schema_insert_rows = "";

        $schema_insert_rows .= (++$row) . "" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows .= $registrarArr[$i] . "" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows .= $registrarArr[$i+1] . "" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows .= $linkArr[$i] . "" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows .= (string)(strip_tags($address)) . "" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows .= (string)(strip_tags($phone)). "" . $sep;
        $schema_insert_rows .= "email test";

        $schema_insert_rows .= "\n";



fwrite($fp, $schema_insert_rows);

fclose($fp);
```

The other column works fine but the ones i commented out are not working [for postal address and email address].. I i get rid of the comments, the data will go to the next row though it should be on the same row as the others.. I checked via var_dump to see if there's < br> but there's none.. What's wrong here?

Comment: The comments probably contain line breaks that screw up your CSV format. You could try wrapping each field into quotes, not sure

Comment: This isn't actually an xls file you're createding, but a tab-separated value file.... .xls is a binary format. It's also easier to use PHP's built-in fputcsv() function to create a tab-separated value file

Answer (score 6):

I've used [PHPExcel](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel) on a client project with good results. It can generate Microsoft Excel, Open Excel and PDF documents.

You might find the file format CSV limiting.

The newer, but not yet stable project is [PhpSpreadsheet](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet).
It also supports more formats.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're trying to make is a CSV file (comma-separated-values) with tab as a separator.

You can use PHP's function [fputscsv](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fputcsv.php) function to accomplish the same task.

Code sample (from PHP manual):

```
$list = array (
    array('#', 'Registrar', 'Country', 'Website', 'Email Address'),
    array('123', '456', '789', 'aaa', 'bbb'),
    array('123', '456', '789', 'aaa', 'bbb'),
);

$fp = fopen('registrars.xls', 'w');

foreach ($list as $fields) {
    fputcsv($fp, $fields, "\t", '"');
}

fclose($fp);
```

Comment: I'm trying to create .xls file, not .csv.. If I get rid of the postal address and the phone columns, everything is fine in .xls format.. I'mm just wondering why the other two information would go wrong ..

Comment: the code you put above attempts to do the exact same thing the fputcsv function does, except it auto-escapes values that might be problematic (which is what I think is breaking your code). Why don't you give it a shot?